# Doubly linked list std::unique_ptr class doesn't work as expected on node removal

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, unique-ptr, doubly-linked-list

Inspired by the talk of Herb Sutter in CppCon2016, [which can be found in this link.](https://youtu.be/JfmTagWcqoE?t=1467)
I decided to implement a doubly linked list as pictured in the video, with smart pointers.
The following implementation is almost working apart from one-line of code in the remove() method.
I debugged this code and the previous node is not updated to null after a removal (as a head node should be).
It's as if the ownership trasfer between the smart pointers is erroneous.
Below is the code for the header file and the test main():

**LinkedList.h**

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <initializer_list>

namespace DLL {
    template <typename T> class LinkedList{
        private:
            struct ListNode{
                std::unique_ptr<ListNode> next; //2 uniq_ptr can't point to one another.
                ListNode* prev = nullptr; //weakptr needs to be cast back to a shared_ptr to check its state.
                T data{}; //Initialize empty;

            ListNode(const T& element){
                this->data = element;
            }
        };
    public:
        std::unique_ptr<ListNode> head;
        ListNode* tail = nullptr;

        LinkedList(){}
        ~LinkedList(){}

        void append(const T& element){
            ListNode* curr = nullptr;
            if (head.get() == nullptr){ //If list is empty.
                head = std::make_unique<ListNode>(element);
            }
            else if(head.get() -> next.get() == nullptr){ //If list has one element
                 head.get() -> next = std::make_unique<ListNode>(element);
                 curr = head.get() -> next.get(); //Sets raw pointer to the first element.
                 curr -> prev = head.get();
                 tail = curr;
            }
            else{
                tail -> next = std::make_unique<ListNode>(element);
                curr = tail -> next.get(); //Sets raw pointer to the last element.
                curr -> prev = tail;
                tail = curr;// The new last element is the tail.
            }
        }

        int remove(const T& element){
            ListNode* curr = nullptr;
            if (head.get() == nullptr){ //If list is empty.
                return -1; //Error: Can't remove from empty list.
            }
            //List has one or more elements.
            curr = head.get();
            while(curr != nullptr){
                if(curr -> data == element){ //Found element
                    if(curr -> prev == nullptr){ //is head
                    //head.reset(head.get()->next.get()); Doesn't work
                    //Line below doesn't work too
                    head = std::move(curr->next); //Head now points to the next element
                    //New head's previous element doesn't point to nothing, as it should.
                    }
                    else if(curr -> next.get() == nullptr){ //is tail
                        tail = curr -> prev; //Reference the previous element
                        tail -> next.release(); //Release the old tail element
                        if(head.get() == tail){
                            tail = nullptr; //tail and head should not be the same.
                        } //List contains one element
                    }
                    else{//is intermediate
                        //The next node should point to the previous one
                        curr -> next -> prev = curr -> prev;
                        curr -> prev -> next = std::move(curr -> next);
                        //The prev node now points to the next one of current.
                    }
                    return 1; //Element found in list
                }
                curr = curr -> next.get(); //Traverse the next element
            }
            return 0; //Element not found in list
        }

        void print() {
            ListNode* curr = head.get(); //Start from the start of the list.
            std::cout << "[ ";
            while (curr != nullptr) {
                std::cout << curr -> data << " ";
                curr = curr -> next.get();
            }
            std::cout << "]" << std::endl;
        }
    };
}

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main() { //Temporary Test Main will be split from the implementation file in the future
    DLL::LinkedList <int> list; //Empty list
    list.append(1);
    list.append(4);
    list.append(5);
    list.append(6);
    list.print();
    list.remove(5);
    list.remove(1); //When 1 is removed the 4 doesn't properly update as head, meaning the previous pointer of 4 is not null
    list.remove(4);
    list.remove(6);
    list.print();
    retunn 0;
}
```

I am sorry for this kind of question, I searched a lot but couldn't find anything like it. I am debugging this for days but couldn't fix the ownership line.
I try to include the minimal amount of code, to reproduce the error I am sorry if the header is a long code segment.

I compiled with g++: `g++ -std=c++14 main.cpp -o out` and with VS2015 compiler.
C++14 flag is needed for the `make_unique` call

Comment: @user4581301 Its not outdated, I shortly justify the use of a raw pointer vs a weak_ptr.

Comment: Thank you. I understand where you are going now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the section where you are checking that the iterator's previous pointer is null (basically checking the head), you have this line:

```
head = std::move(curr->next);
```

which moves the header pointer to be the element's next pointer. However, there's nowhere you update the new head pointer's previous pointer to null. So that code should read something like:

```
if(curr -> data == element){ //Found element
    if(curr -> prev == nullptr){ //is head
        head = std::move(curr->next); //Head now points to the next element
        if (head)
            head->prev = nullptr;
        else
            tail = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Since you're using `std::move` on the item that's becoming the new head pointer (which is correct), you are basically keeping the contained data in that node the same. You need to be explicit in this case - the `std::unique_ptr` wrapper doesn't know anything about the underlying implementation of the object it owns, so there's no way it knows to update the `prev` pointer in this case.

Comment: Worth noting that  the function will now fail if the list has only one element.  `head = std::move(curr->next); ` `next` is null, so `head->prev = nullptr;` dereferences a null.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think this may be why the Asker had the `//New head's previous element doesn't point to nothing, as it should.` comment. Trying to figure why the comment was there is why I noticed this.

Comment: I think they are expecting the smart pointer to automagically clean up on move; that's how I read that comment anyway. Given the opacity of smart pointers of all flavors some confusion is to be expected when starting out...

Comment: Agreed. An extra `if (head)` will solve this, but there might be a sneakier solution I'm not seeing that won't require a wholesale rewrite..

Comment: Hello guys, my expectation was to release the old head node, and make the new node the head of the list

Comment: I started off on the rewrite path - I think there's other ways of doing doubly-linked-lists that are more efficient (one of the few benefits of linked lists is fast insert/delete, and you shouldn't need to iterate). But I figured it was better to keep the answer simple in this case.

Comment: @hitter - yep, your expectation will be met if you explicitly update the new head node's previous pointer with null. Node relationships need to be explicitly managed in this case. You could look at having the ListNode struct handle things like that - it might make it cleaner.

Comment: Agreed again. I recommend updating the code in the answer to something like `head = std::move(curr->next); 
                        if (head)
                        { 
                            head->prev = nullptr;
                        }` for completeness.

Comment: @user4581301 It is indeed an issue it raises an exception in VS2015

Comment: @Varrak I just tested it seems to work, the list is now empty, the debugger shows that the head element has no prev node without leakage this time

Comment: Nice! Definitely worth taking some time playing around with smart pointers. The "Effective Modern C++" book is a good resource - it's very thorough.

Comment: No leaks, but I missed out on clearing `tail` in my suggestion. Needs an `else` case to handle that. Thinking more something like `if (curr->next)
                        { 
                            head = std::move(curr->next); 
                            head->prev = nullptr;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            head = nullptr;
                            tail = nullptr;
                        }`

Comment: @user4581301 I just viewed in the debugger, the tail stores the last position, that is now no existent, because all the nodes were deleted

Comment: Something like `if(head->next == nullptr){ tail = nullptr; }`, should do?

Comment: @user4581301 if you make an answer with the edit on the answer of Varrak I will upvote it